# query did run but no effect on the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
    include '../php_script/connectDB.php';
    $temp=$_POST['resitID'];

     $query="DELETE FROM resit
            WHERE resitid='$temp'";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($result)
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Resit deleted successfully.";
        header('location: ./tutor_delete_page.php'); 
    }
```

The query did run, and the $temp is not empty. But no effect to the database..Pls help

Comment: check what is in your $temp varible

Comment: What is `$temp` value?

Comment: $temp='2015-11-14 12:08:51pm'

Comment: resitid is a column having date values ?

Comment: You might be checking in another database table. Can you verify this. This can happen.

Comment: Submit your full code

Comment: not sure but check permission for your user.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query="DELETE FROM resit
WHERE resitid=".$temp;
```

Comment: What is the difference between `$query="DELETE FROM resit WHERE resitid='$temp'";` and `$query="DELETE FROM resit WHERE resitid=".$temp;` ??

Comment: $query="DELETE FROM resit
WHERE resitid='".$temp."'";

Comment: @jay What is the change in your query. And also it will not work if the $temp is of character datatype.

Comment: @sanjay@nana it Concatenation diffrence see

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM reset WHERE resetid='".$temp."'");
```

Hope this helps,

Sohail

Comment: May I suggest that you change your variable name from '$temp' to something else, as that may be a reserved word which may be creating a confusion.